# RASA Response Selectors: How to reply multiline texts?

Tags: text, markdown, newline, rasa, nlp-question-answering

I would like to use [RASA Response Selectors](https://forum.rasa.com/t/supervised-response-selector-experimental/13714) for a QnA system where **answers are multiline texts**, not just single lines. Say a FAQ system allowing answers are paragraphs of documents.

Take this Q/A example, where question is one-line:

```
 How to follow people on Twitter?
```

and the corresponding answer (real example from twitter FAQ) is a paragraph:

```
 1. Find a Tweet from the account you’d like to follow. 
 2. Hover your mouse over their name.
 3. Click the  **Follow**  button.

 OR 

 1. Navigate to a Tweet from the account you’d like to follow. 
 2. Tap the  icon located at the top of the Tweet.
 3. Tap  **Follow**  from the selection menu.
```

How can I manage this composite / multi line answer with `data/responses.md` Response Selector markdown format?

As far as I undersatnd (please tell me I'm wrong) now in RASA I can just have 1 line for the answer. If that's true, the only solution I found is to insert explicitly a `\n` every newline in the text. So the mentioned example could be translated like that:

```
(venv) $ cat data/responses.md

## ask languages
* faq/ask_how_to_follow_people_on_twitter
  - 1. Find a Tweet from the account you’d like to follow.\n     2. Hover your mouse over their name.\n     3. Click the  **Follow**  button.\n \n     OR \n\n     1. Navigate to a Tweet from the account you’d like to follow.\n      2. Tap the  icon located at the top of the Tweet. \n     3. Tap  **Follow**  from the selection menu.

## ask blablabla
* faq/ask_blablabla
  - blablabla\nblablabla\nblablabla
```

Pretty unreadable, isn't it? It "works" but I don't like it for many reasons:

- the answers on  `data/responses.md` file become unreadable
- I need to write a script that convert FAQs in markdown format, substituting each newline with `\n`s.
- using RASA cli commands (e.g. `rasa shell`) conversation tests, I got the unreadable single line compacted texts :/

---

Two questions:

1. Can I have FAQ answers in responses.md that are composed by multi-line texts (WTSIWYG "as" wrote in the markdown file, possibly whithout inserting `'\n'`)?
2. What's the suggested way to manage RASA Response Selectors answers, in case of  answers made by long texts (~ a page/paragraph)?

UPDATE
I opened the issue/change request: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/5800

Thanks for your help

giorgio

Answer (score 0):

If it is not too late for your project...or for another person coming-in from Google.

If you have long, multi-line texts, I would suggest not to mess up with the domain.yml directly.

It can get ugly pretty fast, and one misplaced indention can break the build.

What I'll suggest instead is a custom action that returns a long-form of text to your satisfaction.

You'll have freedom to do whatever you want.

In python, to do this, you wrap your texts in triple marks like so:

`""" My long form text here """`

It can stretch to any length and span many lines.

Comment: Thx @Wale, but the question is related specifically to response Selectors, see https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/5800. A custom action (that maybe read a text file in case of a long answer, could be a pragmatic solution, even if, also in this case (standard intents) I'd highly prefer to have multiline utterances responses  in domain.yml and not in custom actions.

Comment: BTW, with the custom action way, the advantage of responses in text files could be maybe the possibility to have responses wrote in a template language (mustache, etc.)...